# What UI element was used in the list of Disk Utility

Tags: swift, macos, storyboard, swiftui

In the application Disk Utility is a list with the mount point etc. Which UI element was used to make this list in storyboard? Is there an equivalent in swiftui?

[image: screenshot of disk utility]

Answer (score 0):

> In the application Disk Utility is a list with the mount point etc. Which UI element was used to make this list in storyboard?

NSOutlineView

> Is there an equivalent in swiftui?

List+Section